# Why, when using canvas.toSVG(...) from the FabricJS library, do text boxes move to the right in the exported SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, fabricjs

I'm building a web tool that allows users to make use of FabricJS and place SVG's and wording on a canvas like normal. All seems to work ok apart from when I `canvas.toSVG(..)`

This image shows the tooling, layout is fine.

[image: Preview of the canvas layout within the editor that's been created.]

I then execute a save routine which collects the SVG data using this code:

```
let svg = canvas.toSVG({
    viewBox:{
        x:0,
        y:0,
        width:"480",
        height:"480"
    },
    width:"73mm",
    height:"73mm"
});
```

`

That exports a SVG that has text positions like this: (I've changed the words "YOUR TEXT 1" and "YOUR TEXT 2" in the SVG directly, no further editing)

[image: Preview of the SVG]

Can any one help me understand (and prevent) the text shifting to the right?

I've double checked the textbox is left align.

SVG Source code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="73mm" height="73mm" viewBox="0 0 480 480" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with FabricJS</desc>
<defs>
</defs>
<g transform="matrix(1.7 0 0 1.7 261.74 177.69)"  >
<path style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 4; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(29,29,27); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;"  transform=" translate(-153.38, -104.46)" d="M 153.32 104.4 C 153.51 104.61 153.44 104.5 153.32 104.4 Z" stroke-linecap="round" />
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1.7 0 0 1.7 135.51 200.34)"  >
<path style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 4; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(29,29,27); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;"  transform=" translate(-120.31, -178.37)" d="M 147 164.91 C 146.57730982855682 164.74156317727645 146.1328985846724 164.63382711815294 145.68 164.59 C 145.34176119465357 164.55077327194866 145.00730763880108 164.48388256077817 144.68 164.39000000000001 C 145.0538807224508 163.9020407895281 145.5278177711118 163.49970574102448 146.07 163.21 L 146.19 163.13 C 147.01521351527813 162.57298473632596 147.37373943180302 161.5381485681746 147.07 160.59 C 146.8171706510411 159.70350394183228 145.99116687046657 159.10465120091578 145.07 159.14000000000001 L 145.07 159.14000000000001 C 140.55801397710877 159.0930505636645 136.0557004060644 158.71200843515737 131.6 158 L 128.4 157.57 C 124.09 156.98 119.21000000000001 156.29999999999998 114.92 157.85999999999999 C 112.8981812658202 158.5357419339674 111.10681616562489 159.765789536616 109.75 161.41 C 109.48460137244244 161.76289176899968 109.24402296662738 162.13378347796456 109.03 162.52 C 108.82573769482492 162.91347847881016 108.5774827108301 163.2825061577214 108.29 163.62 C 107.79659666043054 163.94361545214085 107.20717297007282 164.0883242623484 106.62 164.03 L 105.91000000000001 164.03 C 103.76725081016521 164.17628482048406 101.67258878749097 164.73305073899067 99.74 165.67 C 97.78240893670785 166.84193262386145 96.20835827811437 168.55844702859696 95.21000000000001 170.60999999999999 C 94.55000000000001 171.79 93.88000000000001 173.05999999999997 93.21000000000001 174.49999999999997 L 93.06 174.80999999999997 C 92.41584520121985 175.94284556711312 91.96945541618918 177.17718095753884 91.74000000000001 178.45999999999998 C 91.4266286386363 180.1816865615205 92.10211261166131 181.93408498296827 93.49 183 C 93.1388897087357 184.71969726785116 93.02449751632352 186.47931834525022 93.14999999999999 188.23 C 93.19868707256681 188.86277175436925 93.49299484004467 189.45138728932497 93.96999999999998 189.86999999999998 C 94.35327695440456 190.20286685684218 94.85381996707426 190.36851418477602 95.35999999999999 190.32999999999998 C 98.16999999999999 190.07999999999998 99.96999999999998 188.19 101.70999999999998 186.32999999999998 C 102.42279840424666 185.54892498642215 103.18789742372749 184.81723640447322 103.99999999999997 184.14 C 104.9679422597926 183.432300238001 105.99124209936124 182.8036062189196 107.05999999999999 182.26 C 107.67999999999999 181.92 108.29999999999998 181.57999999999998 108.90999999999998 181.2 C 109.6007737900349 180.74239224443457 110.24102668346099 180.21275896086743 110.81999999999998 179.61999999999998 C 111.47217160520408 178.88180711969133 112.27757322056672 178.29481950171515 113.17999999999998 177.89999999999998 C 114.07782568672278 177.6299386238049 115.00408096336969 177.46549475222628 115.93999999999998 177.40999999999997 C 116.79286823352379 177.3519918239958 117.63925433356167 177.22152123940498 118.46999999999997 177.01999999999998 C 120.30470096426143 176.56084236829383 121.92123496807683 175.47489939417713 123.03999999999999 173.95 C 123.51641469594722 173.32988246848754 123.89110096914739 172.637894306271 124.14999999999999 171.89999999999998 C 124.53586191898798 171.9352799717928 124.924138081012 171.9352799717928 125.30999999999999 171.89999999999998 C 125.51311697166933 171.88673447500548 125.71688302833064 171.88673447500548 125.91999999999999 171.89999999999998 C 126.82 171.89999999999998 127.72999999999999 171.89999999999998 128.67999999999998 171.89999999999998 C 128.0262215977255 173.17265558864557 127.44528528477129 174.4814316500137 126.93999999999997 175.81999999999996 C 126.71999999999998 176.34999999999997 126.50999999999998 176.88999999999996 126.28999999999998 177.40999999999997 C 125.78125974581937 178.80467010654317 125.00315676979714 180.08565186182864 123.99999999999997 181.17999999999998 C 122.73389336426233 182.29062075366147 121.12312284309212 182.92998361403824 119.43999999999997 182.98999999999998 C 118.53999999999996 183.08999999999997 117.63999999999997 183.14 116.74999999999997 183.18999999999997 C 113.74999999999997 183.34999999999997 110.66999999999997 183.52999999999997 107.86999999999998 185.25999999999996 C 106.00999999999998 186.40999999999997 104.12999999999998 187.67999999999995 103.20999999999998 189.38999999999996 C 102.67150342510605 190.3868621844371 102.55966982063036 191.55931126361767 102.89999999999998 192.63999999999996 C 103.18262240108511 193.55317852827397 103.82546359334565 194.3115866764465 104.67999999999998 194.73999999999995 C 105.13675096788552 194.94291671945666 105.6123811737499 195.10034361858078 106.09999999999998 195.20999999999995 C 106.5109416327137 195.29634778876573 106.91033698384825 195.43059832696224 107.28999999999998 195.60999999999996 C 107.92528133520918 195.95704375060416 108.53966885256746 196.34103594895308 109.12999999999998 196.75999999999996 Q 109.45999999999998 196.99999999999997 109.78999999999998 197.20999999999995 C 111.54861226712056 198.41903003839394 113.54745325975071 199.234256996139 115.64999999999998 199.59999999999994 C 116.6787808095706 199.76133049812648 117.718647516242 199.8415774465513 118.75999999999998 199.83999999999995 C 122.07993475645895 199.76065297096648 125.3626827414906 199.1216834867533 128.46999999999997 197.94999999999996 C 131.63999999999996 196.84999999999997 135.65999999999997 195.17999999999995 138.52999999999997 192.10999999999996 C 141.03999999999996 189.42999999999995 141.92999999999998 186.10999999999996 142.78999999999996 182.86999999999995 C 142.93999999999997 182.30999999999995 143.08999999999997 181.74999999999994 143.24999999999997 181.18999999999994 C 143.51806732447946 180.15379649374677 143.89342942604802 179.14836229311672 144.36999999999998 178.18999999999994 C 144.60533264517056 177.7799289900738 144.86236421140555 177.38269838771066 145.14 176.99999999999994 C 145.5235938684633 176.48561080185812 145.85837695962988 175.93656653234495 146.14 175.35999999999996 C 146.47517892962048 174.54335582902254 146.61885262507295 173.66078884267165 146.55999999999997 172.77999999999994 C 146.55999999999997 172.50999999999993 146.55999999999997 172.22999999999993 146.55999999999997 171.94999999999993 C 146.55999999999997 171.66999999999993 146.82999999999998 171.39999999999992 147.27999999999997 171.03999999999994 C 147.50726342824436 170.86261753814992 147.72117369621319 170.66876135780316 147.91999999999996 170.45999999999992 C 148.706279809728 169.67272774323368 149.07666049372264 168.56158569124972 148.91999999999996 167.45999999999992 C 148.73213972768107 166.34861394920762 148.01617043022122 165.39771722601878 147 164.91 Z" stroke-linecap="round" />
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1.7 0 0 1.7 236.7 294.23)"  >
<path style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 4; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(29,29,27); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;"  transform=" translate(-183.95, -218.9)" d="M 206.06 195 C 203.04741950123102 193.243500389267 199.71658085623446 192.10149856812532 196.26 191.64 C 193.89999999999998 191.32999999999998 190.67999999999998 191.16 188.88 192.94 C 186.36169765914732 191.22284154449326 183.3063071483885 190.47675781512194 180.28 190.84 C 175.85 191.31 171.96 193.6 168.53 195.62 L 155.89 203 L 155.42999999999998 203.27 C 153.73999999999998 204.27 151.98 205.27 151.27999999999997 207.4 C 150.77661064638076 209.24975405665126 150.74909116124968 211.1967576296757 151.19999999999996 213.06 C 151.41863258904718 214.7708043698634 152.34335265673093 216.3120044826697 153.74999999999997 217.31 C 152.62979358060298 217.75704822112806 151.79017552906285 218.7118351204458 151.48999999999998 219.88 C 150.96999999999997 222.2 152.82999999999998 224.88 154.73 227.21 C 158.57 231.93 163.73 235.21 168.78 238.4 C 170.06 239.22 171.34 240.03 172.58 240.86 C 173.3 241.33 174.01000000000002 241.86 174.71 242.34 C 177.37 244.23 180.12 246.18 183.52 246.78 C 184.51011572918046 246.9569391821806 185.5142063099902 247.04396036585078 186.52 247.04 C 189.66756747681836 246.98223539275938 192.770485079964 246.28475939643823 195.64000000000001 244.98999999999998 C 202.22000000000003 242.14999999999998 208.51000000000002 236.76999999999998 214.34 228.98999999999998 C 214.99858066860574 228.23327530452116 215.462050696649 227.3269339163477 215.69 226.35 C 215.78248144587272 225.21708248218522 215.49004565485157 224.08609586871782 214.85999999999999 223.14 C 214.67999999999998 222.79 214.49999999999997 222.39999999999998 214.30999999999997 222 C 213.56999999999996 220.42 212.73999999999998 218.64 211.21999999999997 217.74 C 209.49999999999997 216.74 207.31999999999996 216.85000000000002 205.21999999999997 217.07000000000002 C 203.15054079183975 217.31135501702929 201.10610932597845 217.7329562685817 199.10999999999993 218.33 C 197.99999999999994 218.65 196.88999999999996 219.01000000000002 195.77999999999994 219.33 C 193.14199127431854 220.27696156130793 190.41965944284786 220.97010140031705 187.64999999999995 221.4 C 183.97999999999996 221.84 180.08999999999995 220.99 175.78999999999996 218.78 L 174.90999999999997 218.34 C 173.5253900304842 217.68126275152915 172.18876665676373 216.92607054537706 170.90999999999997 216.08 C 171.4964412494966 215.99274882111297 172.08741872335523 215.9393271285608 172.67999999999998 215.92000000000002 C 173.73 215.92000000000002 174.81999999999996 215.92000000000002 175.86999999999998 215.92000000000002 C 178.75999999999996 216.00000000000003 181.75999999999996 216.08 184.56999999999996 214.8 C 185.37889627541992 214.39034981729014 186.14300483180068 213.8977008796236 186.84999999999997 213.33 C 187.61501942015764 212.6848236774682 188.48403742284785 212.17423333347512 189.41999999999996 211.82000000000002 C 190.99999999999997 211.32000000000002 192.84999999999997 212.06000000000003 194.47999999999996 212.71 L 195.00999999999996 212.91 C 199.21711423554106 214.50568320542058 203.70446996979848 215.23032821785185 208.19999999999996 215.04 C 210.48999999999995 214.98 212.79999999999995 214.78 214.82999999999996 214.6 C 215.79061201370135 214.55907329031368 216.60727063868597 213.88532992470135 216.82999999999996 212.95 C 218.21 205.14 211.88 198.36 206.06 195 Z" stroke-linecap="round" />
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1.7 0 0 1.7 358.44 211.05)"  >
<path style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 4; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(29,29,27); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;"  transform=" translate(-237.92, -162.32)" d="M 263.22 138.89 C 262.50003758593056 138.79800653915524 261.77566907445816 138.74459687932315 261.05 138.73 C 260.3811596585822 138.7227198510006 259.7133319182056 138.67597190917422 259.05 138.59 C 257.5664138705306 138.33605271336998 256.0976118594991 138.0022340744992 254.65 137.59 L 254.32 137.5 C 251.1061636868579 136.61035347729893 247.8303932578104 135.96188463726298 244.51999999999998 135.56 C 241.06664331374498 135.0946857313514 237.57336238772436 135.00081637825298 234.1 135.28 C 231.12796181807627 135.40587196606583 228.42014027450523 137.02304316569857 226.9 139.58 C 226.16 140.74 225.99 141.01000000000002 225.09 141.02 C 224.51 141.02 223.96 141.02 223.37 140.94 C 222.34864714642242 140.84996243117325 221.32135285357757 140.84996243117322 220.3 140.94 C 216.44 141.37 214.42000000000002 144.01 213.10000000000002 146.26 C 212.24 147.7 211.41000000000003 149.26 210.40000000000003 151.41 Q 210.10000000000002 152.03 209.77000000000004 152.67 C 209.06069453024995 153.93683956162107 208.49390482174306 155.27835366459593 208.08000000000004 156.67 C 207.7787589156287 157.78453323832517 207.937265179277 158.97333021568738 208.52000000000004 159.97 C 208.83053542222038 160.46563187954328 208.9774569809535 161.0463218497742 208.94000000000003 161.63 L 208.94000000000003 165.53 L 208.94000000000003 167.66 C 208.90638500148322 168.58656615247443 209.39242735554714 169.4544989275886 210.20000000000002 169.91 C 211.0493563491537 170.37983283099476 212.08064365084633 170.37983283099476 212.93 169.91 C 213.40762457889156 169.6707900503006 213.79647753967512 169.28544026934392 214.04000000000002 168.81 C 214.56000000000003 167.81 215.67000000000002 167.47 216.96 167.01 L 217.17000000000002 166.94 C 218.87065981264183 166.42035607140124 220.47509012236486 165.6265852865909 221.92000000000002 164.59 C 223.44986275857764 163.33002852749735 224.79620738304132 161.86251288683192 225.92000000000002 160.23 C 226.04000000000002 160.07999999999998 226.15 159.91 226.29000000000002 159.7 C 226.51924273145593 159.28926063532933 226.82870463945414 158.92878852271605 227.20000000000002 158.64 C 227.7041087975828 158.5303731194863 228.22589120241724 158.5303731194863 228.73000000000002 158.64 C 229.10400869075852 158.69854835063248 229.48152184508132 158.73195659437786 229.86 158.73999999999998 C 231.8575525350029 158.6471633405343 233.7661395963415 157.88654561867241 235.28 156.57999999999998 L 235.56 156.35999999999999 C 236.8 155.35999999999999 237.78 154.64999999999998 239.16 154.58999999999997 C 240.67700867837974 154.56780464994665 242.19378649059564 154.64798673693602 243.70000000000002 154.82999999999998 L 245.6 155.01 L 249.6 155.31 C 248.50782945749515 157.53876050688226 246.62585730165426 159.2817233557576 244.32 160.2 C 242.09911907630166 161.00732851609015 239.79997454749412 161.58043888697367 237.45999999999998 161.91 C 235.95 162.17 234.39 162.45 232.84999999999997 162.85999999999999 C 228.70999999999998 163.95 224.98999999999995 165.95 220.68999999999997 168.6 L 220.35999999999996 168.81 C 217.56999999999996 170.53 212.89999999999995 173.4 214.24999999999994 178.2 C 214.52453289971538 179.2473459296585 215.13162079833594 180.17727825991543 215.97999999999993 180.85 C 216.60889700750934 181.30345261714604 217.313092915833 181.64200834230164 218.05999999999995 181.85 C 218.40053705061692 181.95291366274805 218.73448883910532 182.07647582448877 219.05999999999995 182.22 C 219.5521025247155 182.49368015318936 220.02040746912422 182.8081134730066 220.45999999999995 183.16 C 220.78999999999996 183.4 221.11999999999995 183.65 221.45999999999995 183.87 C 222.41892046439594 184.48575138132892 223.4215955436602 185.03053817439584 224.45999999999995 185.5 C 226.48673361730894 186.3845430314694 228.5597513204593 187.15900375148692 230.66999999999996 187.82 C 232.95003320815164 188.6541488155148 235.32490324409207 189.20167896524364 237.73999999999995 189.45 C 238.29999999999995 189.45 238.87999999999994 189.51999999999998 239.46999999999994 189.51999999999998 C 243.4982517041923 189.38710875405351 247.48470713080212 188.65923523575452 251.29999999999995 187.35999999999999 C 256.03999999999996 185.89999999999998 259.19999999999993 183.58999999999997 260.94999999999993 180.35999999999999 C 263.30999999999995 175.94 263.5799999999999 171.04 263.8399999999999 166.29999999999998 C 264.0999999999999 161.55999999999997 264.3499999999999 157.17 266.4799999999999 153.20999999999998 C 266.9843630357532 152.32221475669704 266.9177116588428 151.22050670306044 266.3099999999999 150.39999999999998 C 266.0629789412042 150.0550720616424 265.73731746370555 149.77397478632773 265.3599999999999 149.57999999999998 C 265.600654382853 148.94238751182442 265.696302530659 148.25918645606725 265.6399999999999 147.57999999999998 C 266.43538148536555 146.92783753703708 267.0772696428012 146.10840584669373 267.51999999999987 145.17999999999998 C 268.07316832257345 143.9859523167609 268.0211194585598 142.5992218683976 267.3799999999999 141.45 C 266.4770795616582 139.98593689920722 264.933870261763 139.03626963773323 263.22 138.89 Z" stroke-linecap="round" />
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 238.48 63.09)" style=""  >
        <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="CandyCardCasual" font-size="40" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 4; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" >Sentence 1</text>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 233.59 404)" style=""  >
        <text xml:space="preserve" font-family="CandyCardCasual" font-size="40" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 4; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; white-space: pre;" >Sentence 2</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see [ask] and revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. It's a bit nonsensical now. Don't add tags.

Comment: I didn't add tags, I added the library name.